# Use my own .cs classes in a Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, class, import, using

I'm sure this question is rather stupid...

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project (Project1).
In this project I have a Form (FormPrincipal) and a class (ClassAux).
I want to use methods of ClassAux in the code of FormPrincipal.

I tried with:

```
   using ClassAux;
```

and also:

```
   using Project1.ClassAux;
```

but when I try to use one method (ClassAux has a getInstance() method using Singleton pattern) is says "The name does not exist in the current context".

I also checked and both classes (form and class) use the same namespace.

How should I do?

Thank you

Comment: If the namespace of both the form and the class are the same, you do not need to import its namespace. You should post the code of the class you want to use so we can help more. Pertinent information would be: Are the methods you are trying to use public? Are the methods in the class static? If not, did you create a new instance of your class? `var aux = new ClassAux();             aux.MyMethod();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using VS 2010, I would recommend using the features of your IDE.  If both files are part of your project, it can help create the using.

You said you have a `getInstance()` method.  If this is public and static, then type the following in a method in your form's `.cs` file.

```
var instance = ClassAux.getInstance();
```

Then put your cursor on the word ClassAux, and click **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>**  A couple options will appear in the Smart Tag under the name.  The first one will offer to create the correct using at the top of the file.

The `using` statement at the top only provides a method to shorten the type names in the file, and it can't contain the name of a class, only the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Looks you're mixind up different ideas, keyword **using** is meant for getting access to types from namespaces. To access methods of class X, either create an object of this class or make the method static and acess it directly via classname.